# Как убрать белую полосу при уменьшении масштаба страницы?

Tags: html, css

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;


}

body {
    font-family: Open Sans, sans-serif;

}


header {
    background: url(../background.jpg) no-repeat bottom;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    min-width: 120px;



}


.container {

    margin: 0% 16%;
    position: relative;


}

.top_line {
    height: 80px;
    background: white;
    opacity: 0.7;

    position: relative;
}


.clearfix::after {
    content: '';
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    clear: both;

}




.menu {
    display: block;
    padding-top: 36px;
}

.menu li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-left: 60px;
}

.menu a {
    color: #979b9b;
    text-decoration: none;

}

.menu a:hover {
    color: #eb435c;
}

.help {

    border: 1px solid #eb435c;
    border-radius: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #eb435c;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    right: 3%;

}

.blackout {
    position: relative;
    height: 660px;



}

.blackout:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    right: 0%;
    bottom: 0%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);

}

.arrow {
    position: absolute;
    /* Абсолютное позиционирование */


    border: 15px solid transparent;
    /* Прозрачные границы */
    border-top: 15px solid white;
    /* Добавляем треугольник */
    bottom: 0%;
    right: 50%;
}

.titles {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 40%;
    top: 35%;
    left: 32%;





}

.titles h1 {
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px black;
    font-size: 40px;

    text-align: center;


}


.information {
    position: relative;

}

.order_title {
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #eb435c;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #eb435c;
    text-align: center;

}

.information p {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #858584;

    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bolder;
    width: 59%;
    line-height: 2.0em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 200%;
    left: 21%;







}

.orders {
    margin-top: 250px;
    margin-bottom: 80px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;

}

.orders_item {
    width: 254px;
    color: #858584;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: lighter;
    font-size: 13px;
    padding-right: 40px;



}


.orders_item img {
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.orders_item h3 {
    color: #eb435c;
    padding-bottom: 19px;







}

.number {
    color: #45d3ce;
    font-size: 20px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: -10%;
    left: -24%;

}

.people {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 55px;
}


.about_text {
    width: 260px;

}



.grey {
    background-color: #f4f6f8;



}

.search {
    padding-top: 90px;
    padding-bottom: 70px;
}

.information_all {
    margin-top: 25px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #858584;

    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bolder;
    width: 750px;
    line-height: 2.0em;


}

.all_items {
    width: 770px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0% auto;
}

.buttons {
    margin-top: 80px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;


}

.search_item {

    border: 1px solid #eb435c;
    border-radius: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #eb435c;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 50px;
    margin-right: 30px;

}

.buttons a:first-child {

    padding: 10px 40px;

}

.search_item:hover {
    background-color: #eb435c;
    color: white;
    transition: all .2s linear;
}

.clock_item {
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: -12px 10px 20px -15px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    margin-top: 70px;
    height: 370px;
    width: 260px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 30px
}

.clock_item img {
    height: 180px;
    padding-top: 4px;

}

.clocks_center {
    padding-left: 15px;
    width: 245px;

}

.clock_item:last-child {
    float: right;



}

.clocks {


    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;

}

.text h6 {
    padding-top: 15px;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;

}

.text span {
    color: #eb435c;
}

.all_presents {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 70px;
}

.search_presents {

    border: 1px solid #eb435c;
    border-radius: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #eb435c;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 50px;
}

.contacts h2 {
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #eb435c;
    text-align: left;


}

.contacts .adress {
    padding-top: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: left;
    font-size: 13px;

}

.contacts h3 {
    color: #858584;
    font-weight: lighter;
    font-size: 13px;

}

.contacts {
    padding-top: 80px;
    width: 240px;

}

.adress h3:nth-of-type(1) {
    color: black;
}

footer {
    position: relative;
}

.map img {
    width: 60%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    right: 0%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/media.css">
</head>

<body>
    <header class="header">


        <div class="top_line">
            <div class="container">



                <nav>
                    <ul class="menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Главная</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Премущества</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Каталог</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Отзывы</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Корзина</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>



            </div>
            <a href="" class="help">Помогите выбрать</a>
        </div>
        <div class="blackout">
            <div class="titles">
                <h1>Ваш дедушка мороз живет у нас!
                    Покупайте подарки для детей и взрослых в одном месте!</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="arrow">

            </div>
        </div>





    </header>










    <section>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="information ">
                <div class="order_title">Почему заказывают у нас?</div>
                <p>Хорошие подарки на новый год не так просто найти.Мы предлагаем лучшее.В прошлом году у нас было больше 9435 тысячи заказов из всех уголков Беларуси, каждый клиент остался доволен, обращайтесь и Вы!</p>
            </div>

            <div class="orders">
                <div class="orders_item ">
                    <img src="./order-icon1.jpg" alt="">
                    <h3>Больше-дешевле</h3>
                    <p class="about_text">Скидки до 10%! 1 подарок-1%;
                        2 подарок-2%; и так до 10%.<br>
                        Нужна большая скидка-звоните.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="orders_item">
                    <img src="./order-icon2.jpg" alt="">
                    <h3>Работа без посредников</h3>
                    <p class="about_text">Вся продукция идет напрямую от производителя, а это значит, что мы не ставим наценок на товар</p>
                </div>
                <div class="orders_item">
                    <img src="./order-icon3.jpg" alt="">
                    <h3>Быстрая доставка</h3>
                    <p class="about_text">Быстрая доставка в любые регионы Беларуси за 3 дня, по Минску-доставляем в день заказа.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="orders_item">
                    <img src="./order-icon4.jpg" alt="">
                    <h3 class="people"> <span class="number">9435</span> счастливых покупателей</h3>
                    <p class="about_text">У нас вы найдете подарки для взрослых и детей. Чего-то не нашли? Постараемся помочь, звоните!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>









    <section>
        <div class="grey">
            <div class="container">

                <div class="search">
                    <div class="all_items">
                        <h2>А вот и то, что Вы ищете!</h2>
                        <p class=information_all>Весь ассортимент нашего магазина к вашим услугам. Подарки на новый год- это выражение любви и уважения, помните об этом и выбирайте!</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="buttons">
                        <a href="" class="search_item">Весь перечень</a>
                        <a href="" class="search_item">Мужские</a>
                        <a href="" class="search_item">Женские</a>
                        <a href="" class="search_item">Детские</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clocks">
                        <div class="clock_item">
                            <img src="./clock1.jpg" alt="">
                            <div class="text">
                                <h6>Часы <span>Breitling Navitimer</span></h6>
                                <h6>Цена <span>45рублей</span></h6>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clock_item">
                            <img src="./clock2.jpg" alt="" class="clocks_center">
                            <div class="text">
                                <h6>Часы <span>Breitling Navitimer</span></h6>
                                <h6>Цена <span>45рублей</span></h6>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clock_item">
                            <img src="./clock3.jpg" alt="">
                            <div class="text">
                                <h6>Часы <span>Breitling Navitimer</span></h6>
                                <h6>Цена <span>45рублей</span></h6>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clock_item">
                            <img src="./clock4.jpg" alt="" class="clocks_center">
                            <div class="text">
                                <h6>Часы <span>Breitling Navitimer</span></h6>
                                <h6>Цена <span>45рублей</span></h6>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="all_presents">
                        <a href="" class="search_presents">Все подарки</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>



    <footer>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="contacts">
                <h2>Контакты</h2>
                <div class="adress">
                    <h3>Адрес</h3>
                    <h3>220035 г.Минск, ул.Чичурина, 24-160</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="adress">
                    <h3>Адрес</h3>
                    <h3>220035 г.Минск, ул.Чичурина, 24-160</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="map">
            <img src="map.jpg" alt="">
        </div>


    </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

При уменьшении страницы появляется отступ, чем больше уменьшаешь, тем больше отступ.

Как решить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: К сожалению, в коде, прикреплённом к вопросу, данная проблема не наблюдается

Comment: Хотя вру, наблюдается, но только в Chrome DevTools

Comment: прикрепил весь код

Comment: Не нужно было этого делать, он явно лишний. Убрал его обратно

Comment: проблема исчезала после применения overflow: hidden,но тогда не уменьшалась картина,еще пытался ставить min-width:1200px проблема тоже пропадала, но не адаптировалась

Comment: Вы лучше перепроверьте в других браузерах и на настоящих мобильниках и не ограничивайтесь одним лишь Chrome DevTools

Comment: Хотя нет, вернул код и нашёл. У вас торчит вправо `.orders_item`, который с фиксированной шириной и паддингом выпирает за правый край страницы

Comment: Но пример у вас явно не минимальный. Если бы вы попытались сами удалить всё, что не касается проблемы, то смогли бы сами найти это

Comment: проблема в секциях, но не могу понять где

Comment: В `.orders_item` говорю же

Comment: исправил там, проблема осталась

Comment: Вы пробовали вообще удалить `orders_item` из html-кода целиком?

Answer (score 0):

Просмотрев вашу проблему могу посоветовать используйте(изучите) bootstrap.

А что касается вашего вопроса в `<div class="orders">` для класса `orders_item` необходимо переписать стили, для начала избавьтесь от фиксированного `width:`

```
.orders_item {
    width: 25%;
    color: #858584;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: lighter;
    font-size: 13px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
 .about_text {
    width: 100%;
}
.people {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    /* margin-left: 55px; */
}
```

Для класса `clock_item` сделайте аналогично.

```
.clock_item {
    width: 25%;
}
.clock_item img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Возможно этих исправлений будет достаточно...